# Using concatenate with WordPress Thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails

Hi can someone explain me why the thumbnail is showing outside from the div? am i using the function correctly to concatenate the thumbnail inside the $list. BTW im running this code inside a shortcode that's why i use a concatenate function.

```
$list = "";
$list = " <div class='box'> ". the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail') . "</div>";
```

Comment: Can you please share the output HTML you are getting for the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail` function echoes the result and does not return anything.

If you want to concatenate it this way, you should use [`wp_get_attachment_image`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) instead.

```
$list .= '<div>'. wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'post-thumbnail' ) . '</div>';
```

Comment: Hi sir. Thanks for the help.  btw sir where did you learned this codes .. do i really need to search this 1 by 1 from wordpress documentation

Comment: Ive just checked documentation for that function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/ - it clearly says "Display the post thumbnail.". Yes - development is all about reading docs for tools you use.

Comment: Now i'll read the documents more carefully this time. Thanks sir.

Comment: And also for some one whos using this for post list to get the thumbnail id insert this code.   get_post_thumbnail_id()